# What are the rules for quoting option prices on the market?

Tags: option-pricing

I have implemented a monte carlo pricer for an option. I simply don't know **how many decimals** I need to include in the quoted price. Can anyone please provide guidelines?

Comment: Most exchange-traded options trade in pennies (2 digits past the decimal point); FOREX options trade in pips (4 digits past the decimal point). Some FOREX brokers will quote the underlying in decipips (5 digits past decimal), but I haven't seen anyone do this for options (yet...?)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the website of the exchange that lists the option you care about and look at the contract specifications for that option.